# Use Google Drive API with a device_code from tvOS

Tags: google-drive-api, tvos

I'm trying to use the google drive API using a device_code from the Google API. In the documentation, the Google Drive scope doesn't seem to be listed:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices#allowedscopes

However, in the exact same page, they have an example that uses the Google Drive API in the https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices#callinganapi

When I try connecting using any google Drive scope, with the following request:

```
POST /o/oauth2/device/code HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: accounts.google.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/3.1 (Macintosh; OS X/10.12.4) GCDHTTPRequest
Content-Length: 136

client_id=clientid&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
```

I get this answer:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Tue, 23 May 2017 03:02:31 GMT
Server: ESF
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="37,36,35"
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: Close

{
  "error" : "invalid_scope"
}
```

I'm just wandering since there is a difference in the documentation if it is or isn't possible to do it, if I made a mistake or not.

Comment: If you're testing and want to have [full Drive API scope](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-auth#requesting_full_drive_scope_during_app_development), use "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive".

Comment: Even with that, I get the invalid_scope error